# If you manage to have fixed/have managed to fix your laptop by tomorrow, we can have the lesson even tomorrow

Tags: conditionals

Is the sentence below correct?

> If you manage to have fixed your laptop by tomorrow, we can have the lesson even tomorrow.

Or is it better to say,

> If you have managed to fix your laptop by tomorrow, we can have the lesson even tomorrow.

If both of them are correct, what is the difference between them?

Comment: The second is much more idiomatic. _If you manage to fix_ would also be possible.

Comment: I know this wasn't part of your question, but "we can even have the lesson tomorrow" is what would actually be said in the second clause of this sentence. You may argue: "but doesn't 'even' modify 'tomorrow', not 'have'?" Yes, you'd be partly right, but in fact "even" modifies the entire phrase "have the lesson tomorrow".

Comment: Thank you, @KateBunting
Could you, please, tell me if the first one is wrong?

Comment: Thank you, @PrimeMover, I really appreciate your comment! I want to sound as natural as possible, so any corrections are welcome!
I actually thought of whether I should put 'even' before 'have', but decided to leave it as it is. In Russian, the position of 'even' changes the emphasis slightly, so I thought the same would apply to English. So does it mean it's wrong to put 'even' before 'tomorrow'?

Comment: The first is decidedly odd (that is, the concept of succeeding in having already done something). I didn't notice the 'even tomorrow' part on first reading, but it looks odd to use the word twice in one sentence. "We can have the lesson then" or "as soon as that".

Comment: Thank you, @KateBunting